# Interface Aggregator with generic types

Tags: java, aggregator

I want to do the sum aggregation of a list of Numbers. I would like to do it using generics because we are going to use different aggregation functions.

This is what I would like to have (more less):

```
SumAggregator<Double, Double> sumAggregatorDouble = new SumAggregator<>();
Double sumDouble = AggregatorUtils.aggregate(elements, sumAggregatorDouble);

SumAggregator<Integer, Integer> sumAggregatorInteger = new SumAggregator<>();
Integer sumInteger = AggregatorUtils.aggregate(elements, sumAggregatorInteger);

MinAggregator<Integer, Integer> minAggregatorInteger = new MinAggregator<>();
Integer minInteger = AggregatorUtils.aggregate(elements, minAggregatorInteger);
```

I would like to have a `Aggregator` interface from all `Aggregator` classes implements from.

Could I do this? Maybe someone knows how to do it, or a better way to do what I want.

Edit: This is what I tried

```
public class SumAggregator<I extends Number, O extends Number> implements Aggregator<I, O> { 
    // Attributes 
    private O count; 
    // Constructors 
    public SumAggregator() { 
        this.count = 0.0; 
    } 
    @Override 
    public O apply(I input) { 
        count = count + input; // The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Double, I 
        return count; // Error: Type mismatch 
    } 
    @Override 
    public O getResult() { 
        return count; // Error: Type mismatch 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing you've suggested looks impossible to me. Have you tried doing it? I'm not sure what your question actually is.

Comment: Do you definitely require two type variables? Will you ever add an `Integer` to a `Double` for instance?

Comment: Maybe I am too ambicious... If it is easy to do, it could be good.

Comment: @DuncanJones any idea?